# Collection View Error : request for number of items before section 7 when there are only 1 sections in the collection view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm using a Collection View and I'm trying to switch from one Collection View Layout to another using:

```
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:newLayout animated:animated];
```

Which all seems to work fine and I get a new layout with all my items in.

However, when I switch to the new layout, I want to only show the items in a particular section.  I suppose my first question is, does anyone have any pointers as to correct way to achieve this?

The way I'm doing it is to remove items from the array that is used for the collection view.  To do this, I'm using

```
- (void)removeObjectsInArray:(NSArray *)otherArray
```

to remove the items from my model, and then

```
- (void)deleteSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections
```

to remove sections from the collection view.

On doing this, I get the following error

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData numberOfItemsBeforeSection:], 

/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UICollectionViewData.m:415
2013-05-03 07:35:18.543 Clients[69375:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for number of items before section 7 when there are only 1 sections in the collection view'
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on why I would get this specific error.  Any searching I've done seems to point to similar errors, but not this exact one.  Any thoughts anyone has greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

--- UPDATE

I should have mentioned that I'm doing this inside a gesture recogniser, as that now seems to be important.  I've extracted the code and added a button to run it too.  Running it with the button seems to work (except the animations are off), but doing the gesture still gives me the error.

The code is as follows:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    NSString *selectedMarketSector = [[[[_allMarketSectors objectAtIndex:stacksLayout.pinchedStackIndex] clients] objectAtIndex:0] clientMarketSector];
    NSMutableArray* removeObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableIndexSet *removeSections = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
    for (TBMarketSector* sector in _marketSectors) {
        if (![[[[sector clients] objectAtIndex:0] clientMarketSector ] isEqualToString:selectedMarketSector]) {
            [removeObjects addObject:sector];
            [removeSections addIndex:[_marketSectors indexOfObject:sector]];
        }
    }
    [_marketSectors removeObjectsInArray:removeObjects];
    [self.collectionView deleteSections:removeSections];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self setLayoutStyle:TBLayoutGrid animated:YES];
}];
```

--- UPDATE 2

I finally discovered that my first custom layout was still trying to layout items after I'd removed them from the collection view and the model.  I first had to stop the layout by setting the pinched stack index back to -1:

```
[stacksLayout setPinchedStackIndex:-1];
```

So that the code in the stacks layout would stop trying to layout the items:

```
- (void)setPinchedStackIndex:(NSInteger)pinchedStackIndex
{
    _pinchedStackIndex = pinchedStackIndex;
    BOOL wasPinching = self.isPinching;
    [self setPinching:pinchedStackIndex >= 0];
    if (self.isPinching != wasPinching)
    {
        if (self.isPinching)
            self.gridLayout = [[GridLayout alloc] init];
        else
            self.gridLayout = nil;
    }
    [self invalidateLayout];
}
```

This was from the sample code [from Mark Pospesel](http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/decorationviews/)

So my code now looks as follows:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    NSString *selectedMarketSector = [[[[_marketSectors  objectAtIndex:stacksLayout.pinchedStackIndex] clients] objectAtIndex:0] clientMarketSector];
    [stacksLayout setPinchedStackIndex:-1];
    NSMutableArray* removeObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableIndexSet *removeSections = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
    for (TBMarketSector* sector in _marketSectors) {
        if (![[[[sector clients] objectAtIndex:0] clientMarketSector ] isEqualToString:selectedMarketSector]) {
            [removeObjects addObject:sector];
            [removeSections addIndex:[_marketSectors indexOfObject:sector]];
        }
    }
    [_marketSectors removeObjectsInArray:removeObjects];
    [self.collectionView deleteSections:removeSections];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self setLayoutStyle:TBLayoutGrid animated:YES];
}];
```

That now gives me a separate problem which I guess I should log separately, but essentially, when I pinch a stack out, the stack layout lines all the items up nicely in a temporary grid, but then when it switches layouts to the grid layout they momentarily bounce back into a stack and back out as a grid again.

I suppose that goes back to my original question which is, what is the correct way to switch from one layout to the next -- the photos app on the iPad seems to switch out the view completely, but doesn't seem to 'jump' from one layout to the next, even though there is a pinch gesture going on for example.

Thanks for any additional information anyone can provide.

Comment: show ur removeObjectsInArray: and deleteSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections methods?

Comment: Just updated with a bit more information... thanks.

Comment: can you please share the solution ..